# Transparent border-image flips the gradient of underlying background-color?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a border-image to an a tag that already has a gradient background-color, and I'm finding that the top and bottom bits of the border are rendering the gradient incorrectly. Here's a snippet:

```css
#button {
  padding: 1.5vh 3vw;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A6E8B3, #3DBD8F);

  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png') 30;
  border-image-repeat: round;
  border-radius: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<a id="button">Button</a>
```

My intention is to have the entire rounded area be one smooth gradient bottom to top, with the border going around the edge. Doesn't seem to affect the parts of the background behind the left or right borders, just the top and bottom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that adding `border: 10px solid;` changes what exactly that background image is applied to - by default that is the *padding box* of the element. The added border creates space outside of that padding box, but still within the bounds of the whole element, so that your gradient gets repeated in those areas.

So you can fix this by explicitly specifying that you want the whole border box to be the *background positioning* area, using `background-origin: border-box;`

```css
#button {
  padding: 1.5vh 3vw;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A6E8B3, #3DBD8F);

  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png') 30;
  border-image-repeat: round;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<a id="button">Button</a>
```

Comment: I would add that by default it's padding-box AND it's getting repeated. The repeating is somehow creating this *bad* effect

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, combination of both you could say, perhaps? Padding-box limits what is “one full background painting area” to only parts of the element’s full dimensions, so there is “outside” space where repeating _can_ happen, whereas with border-box the full space becomes “one” painting area, so there is nothing to repeat even if we tried. Toggling `background-repeat` on/off in the original shows quite nicely which “area” is covered, and where repeating can occur outside of it.

Comment: yes exactly what I meant, repeating is creating the *bad* visual effect ... if we remove repeating we can clearly see the difference between both ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif added that to the explanation inside the answer, thanks for feedback!